# Is there any relationship between a functions code body and it's prototype?

Tags: javascript

I have been going through [Javascript Koans](https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/javascript-koans) when I hit upon the part about inheritance. I became deeply fascinated and spent the entire morning researching how inheritance works in JS.

I understand that a function can be used to execute code which is declared in its code body, and a function can also serve the purpose as a constructor for objects which inherent from that functions prototype object.

It seems as though functions have two purposes that are not at all related- the ability to **create objects**, and the ability to **execute it's declared code**. Is there any relationship between these two abilities?

Comment: Well the whole "object creation" process is literally the execution of a function. More precisely, it's the creation of a new instance of the object. What `new` does is to call the function, and if it happens to set some `this` properties, they become the property values of the new instance. Moreover, the `prototype` property allows to add methods to the object.

Comment: I understand that. It just seems strange that functions would have that ability which has nothing to do with their code body.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 It has something to do with their code: as kuroineko said, calling a function with `new` runs its code.

Comment: But that process does not have anything to do with the contents of the code body. The process he described is only concerned with the prototype object and some builtin methods of the Function object.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a simple answer (with some approximations to try and keep it simple)

You could see a "class" function both as the constructor of the underlying object and the place where its methods are defined.

### Construction

The `new` operator will create an empty object whose type will reference the function and bind it to `this`, then call the function.

The function may set some properties of `this`, which will become values for the new instance properties.

### Methods

In JavaScript almost everything, notably functions, can have properties.
Among these, the conventionally named `prototype` property is the container of all class methods (and possibly other property values).

```
function Guy (name) { this.name = name; }
Guy.prototype = {
    sayHello: function () { console.log ("Hello, I'm "+this.name; }
}
```

the `Guy` method `sayHello` is literally the property `Guy.prototype.sayHello`, which happens to be a function.

You could just as well add values instead of functions to the `prototype` property, which would act as class variables (of sorts).

So let's create an object `Bob` from the function/class `Guy`:

```
var Bob = new Guy("Bob");
Bob.sayHello();
```

when you invoke `Bob.sayHello()`, the virtual machine will first look for a `Bob.sayHello` property (which usually does not exist), then for a `Guy.prototype.sayHello` (and would go up the inheritance chain or die trying, but that's another subject), then bind `this` to `Bob` and call `Guy.prototype.sayHello`, which will be able to access the `Bob` instance through `this`.

As an illustration of the mechanism, you can break the prototype chain for a given object instance:

```
Bob.sayHello = function () { console.log ("my real name is Robert"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The duality you're describing doesn't in fact exist. Functions exist to be executed. But, in JavaScript, functions are also objects, so they can have properties such as `prototype`. (You can add other properties to your function and use them from its body as a means of making it "stateful".) From the function's point of view, `prototype` is just another ordinary property.

Object construction is the domain of the `new` operator. What it does, is this:

1. it creates an empty object,
2. it creates a hidden, non-modifiable binding between the created object and its constructor, which is then used to look-up a property value on its `prototype` whenever a property doesn't exist on the object itself,
3. it executes the provided function *in context of that object* (`this` points to it during that function's execution), and
4. it returns either the created object (if the provided function returned `undefined`) or the return value of the provided function.

(The `{}` notation for creating objects is just a shortcut for `new Object()`.)

---

*Additional note on prototypal inheritance (that is used in JavaScript): The second step in the above sequence has an important result. Any object in JavaScript has a constructor (`{}` has `Object` as constructor), so setting an object as the value of `prototype` property of your function doesn't just create a single binding. It transitively creates a "prototype chain". Any property is then looked up first on the object, then on its constructor's prototype, then on it's constructor's prototype's constructor's prototype, etc.*